# deploy one docker image to one ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have some docker images (hosted privately on dockerhub, although I can host them on ECS or anywhere else as well if absolutely need be). I want to deploy to AWS. I want to be able to essentially map one docker image to one ec2 instance and have them be separate. I did my prior research and I found articles mentioning a cluster but that's not what I'm looking to do. Is there a way to simply deploy a docker image on a single EC2 instance?

Comment: What do you mean by mapping an image to an EC2 instance? Running a container with that image?

Comment: yeah precisely that

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to deploy one Docker Image to one EC2 instance in AWS is to use Elastic Beanstalk [Single Container Docker Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_image.html), which will also setup auto-scaling and load balancing for your containers keeping one Container for one EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have docker running on a EC2 instance you can run any docker container there.

So what you need to do is to run a EC2 instance with your preferred OS, install Docker, point the registry to the one you're using and spin up containers. All you need to make sure is that you can access the private registry from your EC2 instance.

Comment: is there a way to automate this for multiple different docker images?

Comment: Once You have docker images you can automate deployment using Ansible http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html#docker-image

Comment: Would this enable me to deploy one docker image to one ec2 instance? i.e. if I have 20 docker images, can I deploy to 20 different ec2 instances?